# How to use securely External Storage for read/Write files in the xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The security scan report showing message as

*The mobile application can access external storage (e.g. SD card) in read or write mode. The application's data stored on the external data storage may be accessed by other applications (including malicious ones) under certain conditions and bring risks of data corruption or tampering.

Risk level:  Medium

Example of Insecure Jave code in the scan report:

```
    /* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    
    /* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
    public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Example of secure code in the scan report :

```
// If you use external storage you should perform input validation.
// In the case that you use external storage for executables files,
// these files should be signed and cryptographically verified.
```

- 

Using below code in our application:

```
var directory = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
           directory = Path.Combine(directory, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
           string file = Path.Combine(directory.ToString(), WebUtility.UrlEncode(customWebView.Uri));
var documentsPath =System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var filePath1 = Path.Combine(documentsPath, WebUtility.UrlEncode(customWebView.Uri));
```

Andriodmanifest.xml:

```
<application android:label="TL" android:allowBackup="false" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyDVTkBTiMl0e2KhzJcuCibAoykSSGEEm6E" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
```

Please help me any one, how write code for securely use of external storage in the xamarin ?

Comment: Your security tool clearly views any use of external storage as insecure

Comment: Hi Jason, Just downloading files purpose ,  we are using above code. is there any way downloading files without using the external storage ? Please help me. .

Comment: yes, don't use the ExternalStorage path.  Use a local app folder instead.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows

Comment: Thanks Jason , I will check & come back. I have one doubt  i.e  After removing the external storage path . is  _android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" require_   in the androidmanifest.xml file ?